# XPath join the string while the string is in between the tag

Tags: xpath

i want to get the data, but the data is split because it has another tag inside,

```
<em>
    <a href="#">
    (1 
        <span>review</span>
    )
    </a>
</em>
```

here's my selector using xpath, i'll try using

```
/em/a/text()
```

but the output was three different result

```
'(1', 'review', ')'
```

iwant ther numbers only i try `text()[1]` but the `'('` still follows

i want the result to be number only or the entire string without any separation, what should i do? so the output must be

```
1 or (1 review)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
normalize-space(//em/a)
```

to get `(1 review )`

or

```
//em/a/substring-after(text()[1], '(')
```

to get `1`